# How to fix boolean value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get this jump/movement system and the bool for a ground check is not changing. When I try the code the value of the bool is its starting value. Here is my code. The code is c# and the engine I am using is unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MOVEMENT : MonoBehaviour
{
     public float playerJumpHeight;
     public GameObject player;
     public float speed;
     public float PlayerXPosition;
     public bool isgrounded = false;
     public GameObject data_to;
     void fixedupdate()
     {
         PlayerXPosition = player.transform.position.x;
     }
      void OnCollisionEnter(Collision theCollision)
 {
     if (theCollision.gameObject.name == "floor")
     {
         isgrounded = true;
         transform.Translate(0,0,1);
     }
     if (theCollision.gameObject.name == "Height_Check")
     {
         isgrounded = false;
          transform.Translate(0,0,0);
     }
 }
 
 //consider when the character is jumping .. it will exit collision.
 void OnCollisionExit(Collision theCollision)
 {
     if (theCollision.gameObject.name == "floor")
     {
         isgrounded = false;
     }
 }
     void Update()
     {
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isgrounded == true) {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) 
              rb.AddForce(Vector2.left); 
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) 
              rb.AddForce(Vector2.right);
     }
 
}
```

Comment: I see you're using `Rigidbody2D` so I assume it's a 2D project. Use `OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D)` and `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your game is 2D, you must use `OnCollisionEnter/Exit` 2D.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision theCollision)
{
    if (theCollision.gameObject.name == "floor")
    {
        isgrounded = true;
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 1);
    }
    // ...
}
```